# Variable 'gestureDetector' might not have been initialized

Tags: java

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
        GestureDetector newGestureDetector = new GestureDetector (ctx, new GestureListener());
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared class OnSwipeTouchListener with final field gestureDetector. In Java, final fields should be initialized during class instance creation.

You need to provide constructor, which will initialize this field.